# how to get data element by title index with capybara "find"?

Tags: html, ruby, xpath, capybara

I have html page:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <th>a</th>
    <th>b</th>
    <th>c</th>
    <th>d</th>
    <th>e</th>
    <th>f</th>
    <th>g</th>
    <th>h</th>
    <th>i</th>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </body>
</html>
```

I need to get data (td tag) by choosing title (th tag).
I'm trying:

```
page.find(:xpath, "//body/td[count(//body/th[contains(.,'a')]/preceding-sibling::th)-1]")
```

and I'm expecting to get "1" as returning value, but it returns "8".
It seems to me, that "count" doesn't work right. So, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic should've counted preceding-sibling `th` **plus 1**, to find the correct position index of the `th` :

```
//body/td[count(//body/th[contains(.,'a')]/preceding-sibling::th)+1]
```

**<kbd>[`xpathtester demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/d38a03855d0a2a6869dce184155fee12)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
<td>1</td>
```

Comment: Therefore I conclude that the xpath expression is correct. But no matter what kind of title (th tag) I choose it always returns "1". Maybe the problem is in capybara "find" method?

Comment: Not necessarily. It will also return "1" (`td` at index 1) when the expression inside `count()` failed to find the target element (which might be an indication that the XPath is not correct) ...